# Separation of output

Tags: list-manipulation, histograms

I have solved two equations with two unknowns and confined my answer in just ten answers. The unknowns are `n` and `k`, and I want to make histogram for them separately, but don't know how to separate the `n` and `k`?
My code is like this:

```
d = 2/100;
lambda = (1.67)*10^(-4);
alpha = Exp[-2*Pi*k*d/lambda];
delta = 4*Pi*n*d/lambda;
R = ((n - 1)^2 + k^2)/((n + 1)^2 + k^2);
Rp = 0.133;
Tp = 0.601;
pts = Table[
  FindRoot[{R (1 + (alpha)^4 - 2*(alpha)^2*Cos[delta])/(1 - 
         2*(alpha)^2*R*Cos[delta] + (alpha)^4*R^2) == 
     Rp, ((alpha)^2*(1 - R)^2)/(1 - 
        2*(alpha)^2*R*Cos[delta] + (alpha)^4*R^2) == Tp}, {n, 
    RandomReal[{1.5, 1.7}]}, {k, RandomReal[{0, 0.02}]}], {10}]
Grid[pts]
```

and what I got is

```
{n -> 1.664, k -> 0.0002223}, {n -> 1.609, 
  k -> 0.0002249}, {n -> 1.669, k -> 0.0002221}, {n -> 1.597, 
  k -> 0.0002255}, {n -> 1.568, k -> 0.0002268}, {n -> 1.592, 
  k -> 0.0002257}, {n -> 1.646, k -> 0.0002232}, {n -> 1.664, 
  k -> 0.0002223}, {n -> 1.568, k -> 0.0002268}, {n -> 1.663, 
  k -> 0.0002224}}
```

Comment: `{n, k} /. pts`

Comment: separate histograms will be like `Histogram[n /. pts]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [ReplaceAll (/.)](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html) and [Applying Transformation Rules](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ApplyingTransformationRules.html)

Your first output and the **Suggesti0ns Bar** giving you more options

[image]

**apply rules to variables** is giving you `{k, n} /. pts`, i.e. `ReplaceAll`, smart!

> {{0.000221347, 1.68536}, {0.000225873, 1.58824}, {0.000223318, 
>     1.64348}, {0.000224683, 1.61414}, {0.000226803, 
>     1.56781}, {0.000225303, 1.60069}, {0.00022273, 
>     1.65605}, {0.000214519, 1.82759}, {0.00022371, 
>     1.6351}, {0.000223122, 1.64767}}

Use this list for further evaluations

```
{k, n} /. pts

ListPlot[%]
```

[image]

```
Histogram[n /. pts]
```

[image]

Comment: george2079 Thank you so much!